# git-pull из одной ветки и git-push в другую

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

Всем здравствуйте!
Ситуация следующая, у меня есть репозиторий приватный, там у меня две ветки main и dev, ветку dev я специально создал чтобы другой разработчик делал поправки (он приглашен через collaborator) и изменение и вливал на ветку dev, чтобы я потом проверил и мержанул на ветку main.
Прошу подсказать, как мне сделать так что бы он делал push только с ветки dev, но pull через main?
или же можно по другому алгоритм сделать?

Comment: Стандартная защита ветки от прямых комментов в gh не работает?

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете назначить ветку main главной, чтоб по умолчанию pull шел из неё. Также вы можете защитить её от прямых push.

Вопрос в том, реально ли вам нужна долгоживущая ветка dev? Если постоянно вливать в неё изменения из main, а потом обратно, это сильно запутывает историю. Если честно, я ни разу не встречал реальной необходимости в долгоживущей ветке разработки.

ИМХО, будет гораздо проще и понятнее, если для каждой доработки (группы доработок) второй программист будет делать короткую ветку от текущей вершины main, и отдавать её вам через pull/merge request. Вы будете провозить анализ кода, вливать, и удалять эту короткую ветку.